# osm2pgrouting import not completed using postgresql-9.4-pgrouting in Debian

Tags: git, postgresql, debian, openstreetmap

I'm trying to import the .osm map of Spain from [Gofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/spain.html) and the import process is stops suddenly before finishing, after the step "Split ways", as you can see below:

```
unknown maxspeed value: 80; 90
unknown maxspeed value: 80; 90
unknown maxspeed value: 80; 90
unknown maxspeed value: 80; 90
unknown maxspeed value: 80; 90
unknown maxspeed value: 80; 90
Split ways
toni@debian:/osm2pgrouting-master$
```

I'm getting the osm2pgrouting from Git [here](https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting), where it's supposed to be up-to-date.
I have created the extensions in my db before starting the import using:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;
```

By using the PostgreSQL shell.

The only thing I can try is getting osm2pgrouting tool from another source, but I'm not sure that's the problem.

**EDITED:**

***SOLUTION:***
I found out the real problem was the extension of the OSM map. Spain is too big for being proccessed by the osm2pgrouting import tool, so I made a grid of 6 pieces and I imported them one by one, adding the data to my postgresql db. That worked for me perfectly.

Comment: What version of pgrouting do you have?

Comment: toni@debian:/osm2pgrouting-master$ sudo apt-show-versions postgresql-9.4-pgrouting
postgresql-9.4-pgrouting:amd64/jessie 2.0.0-3 uptodate

Comment: Ran into a similar problem with version mismatch, looks like that's not what's going on here. Sorry!

Comment: No problem, thank you anyway :)

Comment: I found out that probably the problem is on the .osm map from Geofabrik, since I tried will smaller countries as Luxembourg or Macedonia, and osm2pgrouting is importing them succesfully. Can someone recommend me where else can I get some regional .osm maps?

Comment: You have probably seen this but in case not you can get a bounding box downloads from OSM themselves: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data#Small_amounts_of_data

Comment: Yes! Actually, I just tried with another map from this website, and I'm having similar problems. Do you know if there is any way to debug the import process? The command line doesn't simply catch --debug or --verbose.

Comment: Off hand, the best that I can come up with is to start with tiny areas and work your way up in size, and when you hit errors make sure to check not just postgres logs but also system logs to see any signs of trouble. If that doesn't work, pgrouting has some pretty decent debugging facilities if you're willing to recompile: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/wiki/Developer---How-to-debug

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! By the way, I contacted the contributors of the pgRouting project, and they agree that Spain is such a big sized area for the tool, so the way to solve my problem seems breaking up the area in small peaces or boxes, for example from the overpass-api or the bbbike map extractors.